# How to run Inspector when appium is installed using npm?

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I used npm to install appium, but I don't know how to run the inspector.

I need to use the Inspector to locate elements in iOS.

How can I run inspector while using appium from terimnal and not from graphical app?

Comment: You need to download Appium app to use Inspector. Launch appium server through "appium &" command and then use appium app to inspcet elements.

Answer (score 2):

Appium inspector is not available for command line installation. Better download and install the UI version of appium which support the appium inspector for finding the element easily.

Also Appium inspector won't work in windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

So you can do this by

1. Install npm (which you have already done
2. Install the Appium application (Slavo gave the link to Appium site answer)
3. go to developer settings in the app
4. Check "Use external appium package
5. enter in the location of your NPM install in text area.

When you do this the version of appium you installed via npm will be connected to the GUI application.

The gui does have its own version of the appium server, but it is an older version. That said it will still work, though it will be an old version and connecting the most recent version via an npm install and a gui download is the reccommended approach in the appium docs I think

Comment: It was working till I download Xcode 8. Since I download Xcode 8 it is not working at all. Do I need to change any settings now?

Answer (score 0):

Visit official [Appium website](http://appium.io/)

In the middle of the page there is big blue button with label ***Download Appium***.

Download the client app to run the inspector, but before that you should run **Appium doctor** to check if all dependences were installed properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you have downloaded appium using npm then you will run it through terminal by running "appium" command.
After starting appium server from terminal, open older graphical appium (install it first if you don't have it already). Don't press Launch button from gui. Press apple button and add capabilities there (platform version, device name etc) and press Inspector button.